# Signed measure (convergence of sets)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $\nu:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a signed measure. Then: If $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n\downarrow B$ and $|\nu(A_1)|<\infty$, then $\nu(A_n)\rightarrow \nu(B)$.

Can someone check this proof?

Since $A_1\backslash A_n \uparrow A_1\backslash B$, we have $\nu(A_1\backslash A_n)\rightarrow \nu(A_1\backslash B)$. It is also true to say that $\nu(A_1)=\nu(A_1\backslash A_n)+\nu(A_n)$ holds.

Thus taking limits gives $\nu(A_1)=\nu(A_1\backslash B) + \lim\nu(A_n)=\nu(A_1)-\nu(B)+\lim\nu(A_n)$, provided that $\lim\nu(A_n)$ converges. Hence $\lim\nu(A_n)=\nu(B)$.

How can i ensure that $\lim\nu(A_n)$ does convergence? $\lim\nu(A_n)$ is clearly smaller than $\infty$, but why does it convergence?

Comment: $A_n\downarrow B$ means a sequence $A_1 \supset \ldots \supset A_n \supset \dots \supset B$  ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. Moreover, $B=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$.

Comment: You already have the result. You have proved $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \nu(A_{1}\setminus A_{n})=\nu(A_{1}\setminus B)$. This implies $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}( \nu(A_{1})-\nu(A_{n}))=\nu(A_{1})-\nu(B)$. Now, cancel $\nu(A_{1})$ on both sides using the fact that $\left|\nu(A_{1})\right|<\infty$.

Comment: @Karthik I don't see where he proved $\nu(A_1 \setminus A_n) \to \nu(A_1 \setminus B)$. I'd say you are assuming the measure is continuous

Comment: @user1952009 This is just because $A_1\backslash A_n \uparrow A_1\backslash B$.

Comment: @peer isn't $\lim_n \nu(A_1 \setminus A_n) =\nu( \lim_n A_1 \setminus A_n)$ some form of continuity of the measure ?

Comment: @user1952009 Well, i used the fact that for $A,A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_n\uparrow A$ $\mu(A_n)\rightarrow\mu(A)$ is always true, if $\mu$ is a signed measure.